# What is the equivalent of datetime.datetime.now() in postgres?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have my code and want to return the current time in SQL (I'm using postgres).

```
procedure = PGFunction(
  schema="public",
  signature="in_out(_profile_id integer, _item_id integer, _channel_id integer, _allowed Boolean, _source_datetime timestamp)",
  definition="""\
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE sql AS $$
    INSERT INTO local_cache(profile_id, item_id, channel_id, source_datetime)
    VALUES(_profile_id, _item_id, _channel_id, _source_datetime)
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT local_cache_pkey
    DO UPDATE local_cache
    SET source_datetime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP??
    WHERE _source_datetime > source_datetime
    AND profile_id = _profile_id 
    AND item_id = _item_id 
    AND channel_id = _channel_id
$$;"""
)
```

Is it "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"? Also how do I return a row count in SQL showing how many rows were affected by the execution of this stored procedure (how many rows were updated, not updated)? I'm not sure if I should use SELECT COUNT(*) it'd be rather slow

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a Postgres function that should do what you want.  But it looks like you're already calling it?  What is the problem?

Comment: You can use `SELECT NOW()` or `SELECT NOW()::timestamp`

Comment: yes i am calling it here: "SET source_datetime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP??" i put question marks because I wasn't sure if that's the right function.

Comment: _I wasn't sure if that's the right function_ Well, is it doing what you want?  If so, then yes, it is the right function

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Answer (score 1):

If you want the timestamp from the start of the database transaction, use `current_timestamp`. That function returns the same value for all calls in a database transaction.

If you want the current system clock timestamp, use `clock_timestamp()`.